# ember Uncaught Error: assertion failed: Unable to find view at path

Tags: ember.js, mouseover

I am trying to learn ember.js and i started by trying to set up a simple (not so simple) mouseover, out, down  example for myself.

http://jsfiddle.net/RBbpS/48/

I keep getting a "Uncaught Error: assertion failed: Unable to find view at path"

Can someone shed some light on this I am sure it is something simple.

Comment: OK i got the click to work by including everything in the HTML instead of the javaScript http://jsfiddle.net/RBbpS/49/ but the mouse over still does not work

Comment: It's better to update your question rather than commenting if you have made progress. Also, can you copy your JSFiddle code into the body of the question?

Answer (score 2):

Your first fiddle works if you declare the App as a global (without the var).

http://jsfiddle.net/Sly7/RBbpS/52/

That beeing said, if you're new to ember, I advice you to starts with reading emberjs.com (do not forget the api:), where you can find what are the handlers for a view

from the doc:

```
Mouse events: 'mouseDown', 'mouseUp', 'contextMenu', 'click', 'doubleClick',
'mouseMove', 'focusIn', 'focusOut', 'mouseEnter', 'mouseLeave'
```

Finally, the version you use here is a quite old one, I suggest you to try the latest release: http://cloud.github.com/downloads/emberjs/ember.js/ember-latest.js (do not forget to include also http://cloud.github.com/downloads/wycats/handlebars.js/handlebars-1.0.rc.1.js

Comment: Thanks I cannot vote you up since this is my first post. Also if i use ember-latest.js it does not work

Comment: could you provide the corresponding jsfiddle please ? Then I can update my answer

Comment: Thanks a lot for mentioning the global thingy; fixed my bug!

Answer (score 0):

Try mouseEnter and mouseLeave instead mouseOver and mouseOut . Refer the ember.js view events [guide](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.View.html)

Comment: I knew it was something simple. Thanks